# Strange error trying to do a shared_ptr swap()

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, swap, make-shared

I'm a relative C++ newbie trying to convert an existing project from raw pointers, with a convoluted memory-management protocol, over to using C++11's `shared_ptr`.  Overall it is going very smoothly, and I *think* I understand how `shared_ptr` works in terms of move semantics, rvalue references, etc.  Good stuff.

However, I have hit a weird error that I don't understand and don't know how to fix.  A little background first.  I have a class hierarchy rooted in an abstract base class named `EidosValue`, and a class named `EidosValue_Int_vector` is (indirectly) a concrete subclass of that:

```
class EidosValue
class EidosValue_Int : public EidosValue
class EidosValue_Int_vector : public EidosValue_Int
```

My code generally traffics in `EidosValue`, but sometimes, especially when creating a new value, I need to handle a specific subclass.

I have done typedefs for the `shared_ptr`s for these classes, so I have:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<EidosValue> EidosValue_SP;
typedef std::shared_ptr<EidosValue_Int_vector> EidosValue_Int_vector_SP;
```

among others.  OK, so now to the core of the problem.  I have a function that returns an `EidosValue_SP` that it creates.  Depending on the logic within the function, it might create one of several different concrete subclasses of `EidosValue`.  So I do something like this:

```
EidosValue_SP MyClass::MyMethod(...)
{
    EidosValue_SP result;

    if (...)
    {
        EidosValue_Int_vector_SP int_result_SP = make_shared<EidosValue_Int_vector>();
        ... do subclass-specific stuff with int_result_SP...
        result.swap(int_result_SP);
    }
    else (...)
    {
        ...similar logic for other subclasses...
    }

    ...other shared logic...
    return result;
}
```

The problem is with the `swap()` call.  I get an error: "`Non-const lvalue reference to type 'shared_ptr<EidosValue>' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'shared_ptr<EidosValue_Int_vector>'`".  This is puzzling since `EidosValue_Int_vector` is not an "unrelated type", it's a public subclass of EidosValue, and the code here knows it.  If I type `result = make_shared<EidosValue_Int_vector>();` the compiler has no problem whatsoever with that, so it clearly knows that the types are related and compatible.  It just doesn't like it in the context of `swap()` for some reason.  In other places in my project I have been able to simply do a `return int_result_SP;`, with a declared return type of EidosValue_SP, and that has worked fine – the compiler is happy to consider an EidosValue_Int_vector_SP to be an EidosValue_SP in that context – but I can't do that here because of the shared logic at the bottom of the function.

I am somewhat constrained in my implementation here because this code is a bottleneck and needs to run fast (and yes, I know that from actually instrumenting the code, and yes, it really does matter).  So it is essential to use `make_shared` to avoid a double allocation, and I would also strongly prefer to avoid a refcount increment/decrement when I hand the pointer from `int_result_SP` to result; I don't want there to be a moment in time when there are two shared_ptrs pointing to the new instance.  So `swap()` seems like the obvious way to go; but I'm blocked by this compiler error.  Why is it happening and how can I fix it?  Thanks!

ADDENDUM:

Oh, pondering this further I bet I know why the error is happening.  `swap()` has no objection to putting the `EidosValue_Int_vector` into the `EidosValue_SP`, but it **does** have a problem with putting the `EidosValue` into the `EidosValue_Int_vector_SP`; in that direction the types are not compatible.  I hadn't thought about it that way since `result` has no value (i.e. has `nullptr`, I guess) in it; but of course `swap()` doesn't know that.  OK, so if that is the problem, the question remains: how can I effect the transfer while keeping the code fast – not doing a refcount inc/dec and not moving away from using `make_shared`?  Now that I understand the problem (I think) it seems likely that there is just some API or trick that I have overlooked...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what `std::move` is for. Use:

```
    result = std::move (int_result_SP);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't `swap` because, although `EidosValue_Int_vector` *is a* `EidosValue` the converse isn't true.

Comment: Yep, I figured that out just after I clicked post.  See the addendum I just put up.  The question remains how to make my code work.

Comment: just `result = int_result_SP;`. No swap is needed

Comment: "while keeping the code fast" - what makes you think the assignment is making your code **not** fast?

Comment: @qehgt, result = int_result_SP would cause a refcount increment/decrement, would it not?  After the assignment, both result and int_result_SP would point to the object, and that would remain true until int_result_SP went out of scope and the refcount decremented again.  Am I mistaken in how that works?

Comment: @bhaller, you can assume that this increments/decrements are _very_ cheap operations vs dynamic allocation of your object in heap.

Comment: @qehgt, sure, but that could be like saying that elephants are very small compared to blue whales.  :->  David Schwartz seems to hit the nail on the head with his answer, which avoids the overhead of the increment/decrement entirely.  (Although it would be interesting to profile both and compare; perhaps once I've got my code running I will do that.)

Comment: @bhaller, it's literally just a few CPU instructions if optimizations are enabled.

Comment: Unless the compiler decides not to inline the operator= function call, in which case it's a function call.  In any case, this code is hot enough that a few CPU instructions matter.  Why would you use a solution that causes a refcount inc/dec if there is an equally good solution that avoids that?